# Java MongoDB - specify which forEach to use

Tags: java, mongodb, foreach

I am using Java 8 and MongoDriver 3.5 for a Java project

I retrieve a `FindIterable<Document>` with the method `collection.find()`, and I would like to use a **forEach** on this Iterable, but I have a problem with my forEach

Here is my code so far

```
MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(url);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");

FindIterable<Document> documentList = collection.find();

documentList.forEach((Document document) -> {
    System.out.println(document.toJson());
});
```

Spring Tools Suite doesn't give me an error, however when I compile my code, I got the following error

```
error: reference to forEach is ambiguous
documentList.forEach((Document document) -> System.out.println(document.toJson()));
                    ^
both method forEach(Consumer<? super T>) in Iterable and method forEach(Block<? super TResult>) in MongoIterable match
  where T,TResult are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in interface Iterable
    TResult extends Object declared in interface MongoIterable
```

So, I was wondering, is there a way to tell Java to use the native forEach method instead of the mongo one ? 
For example in php you can do something like /*@var $foo String*/ to help compiler

PS : I know I could use a for(Document document : documentList) but we still have a problem with the cursor not being closed on error. (as seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469815/5578655) ) but if my question is really unsolvable, I can use this fallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use casting to required method implementation (in your case the one from Iterable interface):

```
documentList.forEach((Consumer<? super Document>) (Document document) -> {
    System.out.println(document.toJson());
});
```

it's strange that Spring Tools Suite doesn't display you an error, meanwhile IntelliJ Idea does, it displays "Ambiguous method call"   :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try this tonight ! Yeah I also found akward that STS doesn't display it.... Maybe switching to IntelliJ latter could be an option

Comment: forEach works fine for me. you could report a bug to STS regarding your ambiguous issue.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks !