# Java and MongoDB: forEach(Block<? super Document>) is ambiguous

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to extend the Azure Java / MongoDB [simple example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-java-getting-started) with a filter from [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/) while getting my head around functional Java. The below code is throwing errors

```
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("my-db");
        Document queryResult = collection.find(Filters.eq("fruit", "apple")).first();

        Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("param", 2293), Filters.eq("param1", 202));
        final Document queryResult2 = collection.find(filter).forEach(doc -> 
        System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

is giving me the following error

```
The method forEach(Block<? super Document>) is ambiguous for the type FindIterable<Document>",
```

I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023751/java-mongodb-specify-which-foreach-to-use) and tried various things including below but my lack of experience with `forEach` is obvious!

```
           //cannot convert from void to document error
            Document queryResult2 = collection.find(filter).forEach((Block<? super Document>) doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));

            //cannot convert from void to document error
            final Document queryResult2 = collection.find(filter).forEach((Consumer<? super Document>) (Document document) -> {
                System.out.println(document.toJson());
            });
```

All help/tips appreciated

Comment: What is the version of your Java driver? Check the API docs for your driver version.

Comment: it was 3.4.2, after your question I updated to 3.12.11 but the error remains

Comment: What do you intend to do with `forEach` loop?

Comment: collect all documents that match my filter and write them as a consolidated file to a file store

Comment: @user1843591 Remove the left hand side of the assignment i.e. `final Document queryResult2 =`

Comment: For your driver version try this: `collection.find(filter).cursor()` returns a `MongoCursor` (you can use its methods for iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

```
Document queryResult2 = collection.find(filter).forEach((Block<? super Document>) doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

`forEach` has a return type of `void`, it doesn't return anything. So the assignment is wrong. That's why you get `cannot convert from void to document error`

Secondly `Document`, represents a single document, not a collection of documents. So the assignment to simply a `Document` object is wrong as well.

Try something like this:

```
List<Document> documents = collection.find(filter).map(doc -> doc).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Here's the link to the `forach` and `map` Mongodb [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html).