# MongoDB - Implementing nor query in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have the following query which I am trying to implement in Java (I am using 3.4.2 mongo-java driver) :

Json:

```
     {
      "_id" : "Team:2334918",
      "fieldName" : [
                "Delivery",
                "Support"
            ],
      "isDeleted" : false
      }
```

Here the query:

```
  db.myCollection.find({$nor: [{“fieldName”: {$exists: false}},{“fieldName”:{$size:0}}]})
```

I have written the following code to implement the above query:

```
    MongoClient mc = ctm.getMongoConn();
     db = ctm.getDatabase(mc);
     col = db.getCollection(collectionName);

    BasicDBObject searchObject = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> searchArguments = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    searchArguments.add(new BasicDBObject("fieldName",new BasicDBObject("$exists",false)));
    searchArguments.add(new BasicDBObject("fieldName",new BasicDBObject("$size",0)));
    searchObject.put("$nor", searchArguments);

    MongoCursor<Document> curs = (MongoCursor<Document>) col.find(searchObject);

    while (curs.hasNext()){

             Document doc = curs.next();
             Object name1 = doc.get("fieldName");

             System.out.println(name1.toString());
             j++;
         }
```

I am getting the following error while running:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl cannot be cast to com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor
```

Comment: Try  `MongoCursor<Document> curs = col.find(searchObject).iterator();` Also you are mixing Document (3.x) and BasicDBObject (2.x). You can replace your search builder with `Filters filters = Filters.nor(Filters.exists("fieldName"), Filters.size("fieldName", 0);`

Comment: thanks @Veeram, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
MongoCursor<Document> curs = (MongoCursor<Document>) col.find(searchObject);

while (curs.hasNext()) {

}
```

With this:

```
FindIterable<Document> docs = col.find(searchObject);

for (Document d : docs) {

}
```

The suggestion from @Veeram (in the comments above) is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`MongoCursor<Document> curs = col.find(searchObject).iterator();` to get cursor.

You don't have to get hold of cursor. You can use the methods provided in the `FindIterable` which iterates the cursor for you. example at the end.

Also you are mixing `Document` (3.x) and `BasicDBObject` (2.x). You can replace your search builder with

```
Filters searchObject = Filters.nor(Filters.exists("fieldName"), Filters.size("fieldName", 0);
FindIterable<Document> curs =  col.find(searchObject);
curs.forEach();
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424894/java-syntax-with-mongodb) by the author.